# How to increase id by 1 or change it completely in HTML using PHP code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting all the results from database and showing them in a datatable using this query

```
  $result['getTableGroup'] = $this->getTableGroup();
  return $this->load->view('users/index', $result);
```

and here is my code of view

```html
<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Group Users</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($getTableGroup as $value) : ?>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <?= $value->group_name ?>
         </td>
         <td>
            <?php if ($value->group_status == 'on'): ?>
            <div class="switch">
               <div class="onoffswitch">
                  <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example1" name="group-status">
                  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example1">
                  <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <?php elseif ($value->group_status == 'off'): ?>
            <div class="switch">
               <div class="onoffswitch">
                  <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example2" name="group-status">
                  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example2">
                  <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

code is working fine the problem is here as im using an `onoff switch` now this is a list and the id in `input and label` will be same so the code of this section not working fine i am trying to generate some `random numbers or loop` to increase by one to i can put that changer in `id and label` so every time each `<td>` runs so the `id` in label will change and then only code will work fine

```html
<td>
   <?php if ($value->group_status == 'on'): ?>
   <div class="switch">
      <div class="onoffswitch">
         <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example1" name="group-status">
         <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example1">
         <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
         <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php elseif ($value->group_status == 'off'): ?>
   <div class="switch">
      <div class="onoffswitch">
         <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example2" name="group-status">
         <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example2">
         <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
         <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: My advice would be for this kind of tasks, always iterate keys with values: `foreach( $arr as $k => $v ) {// use $k that is zero based, but if you need a natural order you may output $k + 1}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to set id dynamic then set a variable then use it . i use $i first 1 then increase it so id will be unique.if you need something else then inform. i use $i = 1; then increment it last so it will dynamic

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Group Users</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($getTableGroup as $value) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <?= $value->group_name ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php if ($value->group_status == 'on'): ?>
                    <div class="switch">
                        <div class="onoffswitch">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example<?= $i ?>"
                                   name="group-status">

                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example<?= $i ?>">
                                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php elseif ($value->group_status == 'off'): ?>
                    <div class="switch">
                        <div class="onoffswitch">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example<?= $i ?>"
                                   name="group-status">

                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example<?= $i ?>">
                                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <?php
        $i++;
    } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: super dooper it works just perfect. thank you @Shafiqul Islam

Comment: thank you and happy to help, can you accept my answer?

Comment: @AbdullahFraz you can not do up vote , you can accept answer.if you accept answer then you get 5 point and also me

Comment: @AbdullahFraz you accept other answer, my answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use incrementer  variable like below

**1st :** Declare the variable $i=1;

**2nd :** Each time of loop increment one $i++;

```
<?php $i=1; foreach ($getTableGroup as $value) : ?>
  ......
  <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="checkbox<?php echo $i; ?>" name="group-status">
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example<?php echo $i; ?>">
  ......
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use auto increment . use the code as following

```
 <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Group Users</th>
                                                <th>Status</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <?php 
                                            $i = 0;
                                            foreach ($getTableGroup as $value) : 
                                            $i++;
                                            ?>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <?= $value->group_name ?>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <?php if ($value->group_status == 'on'): ?>
                                                            <div class="switch">
                                                                <div class="onoffswitch">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example<?php echo $i; ?>" name="group-status">

                                                                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                                                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                                                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        <?php elseif ($value->group_status == 'off'): ?>
                                                            <div class="switch">
                                                                <div class="onoffswitch">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example<?php echo $i; ?>" name="group-status">

                                                                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                                                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                                                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    </td>

                                                </tr>

                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```